# Node not moving after changing scenes

Tags: xcode, swift

I made a (basic) game, works perfect, goes to GameOverScene, and when it comes back from GameOverScene to GameScene, the player(spritenode) is not moving anymore..

I commented in the GameScene code which functions its about

I get no error from Xcode!

the bug is in the gamescene.swift file(functions: swipedRight + swipedLeft + swipedUp + swipedDown):

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var kikker:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var auto1:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var lastYieldTimeInterval:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastUpdateTimerInterval:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
let playerCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let auto1Category:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0

required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoder not supported")
}

override init(size:CGSize) {
    super.init(size:size)
   anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:1.0)
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg5")
   var auto1:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "auto1")
   background.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
   background.anchorPoint=CGPoint(x:0,y:1.0)
   addChild(background)
    kikker = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"kikker5")
    kikker.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)
     kikker.xScale = 0.22
   kikker.yScale = 0.22
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
   kikker.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
    kikker.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = auto1Category
    kikker.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    kikker.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    kikker.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: kikker.size.width/2)
    kikker.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
     kikker.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, -610)    
   addChild(kikker)    
    println(kikker.position)
}

 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
       var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody
    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if((firstBody.categoryBitMask & auto1Category) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) != 0)
    {
    println("aasda")
    aangereden(contact.bodyB.node as SKSpriteNode, player: contact.bodyA.node as SKSpriteNode)  
    } 
}

func addCar(){
    var auto1:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "auto2")
    auto1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(auto1.size.width/2,     auto1.size.height/2) )
auto1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    auto1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = auto1Category
    auto1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
    auto1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    auto1.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    let position : CGFloat = 51 + (CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(4)+2)*(-111))
    auto1.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)
    auto1.position = CGPointMake(-auto1.size.width/2, position)
    self.addChild(auto1)
    let minDuration = 2.5
    let maxDuration = 4.0
    let rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration
    let duration = Int(arc4random()) % Int(rangeDuration) + Int(minDuration)
      var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(375 + auto1.size.width/2, position), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())
      auto1.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
}

    println("DOOD")
    player.removeFromParent()    
}

func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate:CFTimeInterval){
    lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
    if (lastYieldTimeInterval > 2.5){
        lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
        addCar()
    }
    }

//#1 function not working after changing scenes: the function is executing, the println works 
but for some reason the runAction doesnt do its job, the node(kikker) is not moving as it should
func swipedRight1(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    var naarRechts = SKAction()
    var positionX = kikker.position.x

    println("right2") 
    if(kikker.position.x<200){
        println(positionX)
        positionX = kikker.position.x + 125
        println(positionX)
        naarRechts  = SKAction.moveToX(positionX , duration: 0.25)
        kikker.zRotation=(-1.570)
        kikker.runAction(naarRechts)

    }
}

//#2 function not working, same story
func swipedLeft1(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    var naarLinks = SKAction()
    var positionX = kikker.position.x
    if(kikker.position.x>150){
        positionX = kikker.position.x - 125
        naarLinks  = SKAction.moveToX(positionX , duration: 0.25)
        kikker.zRotation=(1.570)
        kikker.runAction(naarLinks)
    }
}

//#3 function not working, same story
func swipedDown1(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    var naarBeneden = SKAction()
    var positionY = kikker.position.y
    if(kikker.position.y>(-600)){
    positionY = kikker.position.y - 111
        naarBeneden = SKAction.moveToY(positionY , duration: 0.25)
        kikker.zRotation=3.141
        kikker.runAction(naarBeneden)
}
}

//#4 function not working, same story
func swipedUp1(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    var naarBoven = SKAction()
    var positionY = kikker.position.y

    if(kikker.position.y < (-60)){
    positionY = kikker.position.y + 111
        naarBoven = SKAction.moveToY(positionY, duration: 0.25)
    kikker.zRotation=0
        kikker.runAction(naarBoven)
      }

    if(positionY > (-60)){
                var gameOverScene:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
                self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
   var timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastUpdateTimerInterval
    lastUpdateTimerInterval = currentTime

    if (timeSinceLastUpdate > 1){
        timeSinceLastUpdate = 1/60
        lastUpdateTimerInterval = currentTime
    }
    updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate)
}
}
```

here the GameOverScene file:

```
 import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameOverScene: SKScene {

override init(size:CGSize){
super.init(size:size)

    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    var message:NSString = NSString()
    message = "Game Over"
    var label:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"DamascusBold")
    label.text = message
    label.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(label)
    var scene:GameScene!
    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0),
    SKAction.runBlock({
       // var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        var scene1:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene1)
    })
    ] ))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

gameviewcontroller file:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

var scene:GameScene!

func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    scene.swipedRight1(sender)
}

func swipedLeft(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    scene.swipedLeft1(sender)
}
func swipedDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    scene.swipedDown1(sender)
}
func swipedUp(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    scene.swipedUp1(sender)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   let skView = view as SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
  let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
     let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code by removing all unnecessary blank lines - one is ok, two might be ok, three or more are not. Also it would be good to at least specify the name of the method to look for, or some text to search so that readers don't have to scroll the code line by line to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling your `swipedUp1` (etc) methods on the wrong scene. Here's what's happening:

1. Your view controller has a reference to the `GameScene` instance that you start with. Its gesture action methods call to that, and all is well.
2. When you start a new game from `GameOverScene`, that creates a *new* instance of `GameScene` and presents it in the view. Now you have **two** instances of `GameScene`: the one your view controller is still pointing to, and the one the view is now rendering.
3. When you're gesture actions fire, they're still talking to the first `GameScene`. So your log lines get printed, but you don't see anything happen because the second `GameScene` is the one being displayed.

You probably don't want two scenes sticking around, anyway.

You can fix both problems by eliminatimg the `scene` property in your view controller and having your gesture actions call through to `view.scene` instead (after appropriate casting):

```
func swipedUp(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedUp1(sender)
}
```

This way, the swipe goes to whichever scene the view controller's `view` is currently presenting.

Alternatively, you could keep your original `swipedUp` (etc) code, and change `scene` from a stored property to a read-only computed one that always gets you the currently presented scene:

```
var scene: GameScene {
    let skView = view as SKView
    return skView.scene as GameScene
}
```